# How to achieve thinner-thicker shadow effect

Tags: css

Is there a way to achieve this type of shadow?
It's solid and thin on the bottom side and it gets thicker and more blur on the top side.

[image: shadow example]

```css
.shadow {
  width:100px;
  margin:20px;
  background:red;
  border-left:10px solid grey;
  border-right:10px solid grey;
  border-bottom:200px solid red;
  box-shadow:0 -5px 5px 5px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>
```

Comment: excuse me,I 'll post what I 've already tried (and my code) in a second..
the thing is that I tried a million of things,and EVERY time,my shadow was solid..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clip-path and a gradient can approximate it:

```css
.box {
  --s:15; /* control the size */

  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  border-left: calc(var(--s)*1px) solid;
  border-right:calc(var(--s)*1px) solid;
  border-image:linear-gradient(transparent,#555) var(--s);
  background:red padding-box;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,calc(100% - calc(var(--s)*1px)) 100%,calc(var(--s)*1px) 100%)
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: That was so so helpful..Thanks so much!! I 've tried a lot of things,but everytime it was solid..(sometimes,it wasn't even working..)